# How to get entity framework to realize the model and the DB are in sync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first for the first time in a production environment. Everything went fine until we got the DB up and had put some of the data in it and then to get some of the data we were importing from another location we had to change field lengths. So we made some of the fields nvarchar(99) instead of nvarchar(50).

That went fine and the application still worked but I knew I needed to change the data annotation or it would blow up later when it loaded and tried to save a too long field. When I did that the app blew up even though the model and the db are now matching. So I thought that it was the hash in the metadata table so I thought I'd be clever and make a new DB and take the hash from there and copy it. That did not work and in fact now I cannot get my app to connect to the test db that we have data loaded in at all.

I do not want to drop and recreate this database. I want entity framework to realize that the model and the schema do in fact match. Is there any way for me to do this? Also why did copying the metadata from a DB that entity framework created with this model not work?

Comment: Is it on the same database server? If not are database servers the same edition?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say, "...the app blew up?" That doesn't give us much to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework Code First creates a `EdmMetadata` table and saves a hash of your Model classes in it. When you change something in the Model, the hash of the new Model classes doesn't match what's in the `EdmMetadata` table anymore, and the app should "blow up" at runtime. What you need to do to keep using the same database without dropping it, is to delete the `EdmMetadata` table. This way EF will not do that check and will try to proceed with the access to the DB.

Check this [video tutorial](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) (skip to 8:10 of the "When Classes Change" section).

Comment: I understand that part. I thought I could work around it by letting the app create a new DB somewhere else on the server and copying the metadata but turns out there's something more than just hashing the model going on behind the scenes. I tried deleting the metadata table and the app will start now and doesn't complain until it tries to access a many to many relationship that I had. I now get the error -
$exception {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}
Inner Exception-
-  InnerException {"Invalid object name 'dbo.GroupPersons'."}

Comment: Maybe there's some "magic" going on when hash the Model classes, I don't know about that.
That error you're getting now probably has to do with the Model not matching the DB. Looks like EF is expecting a table called dbo.GroupPersons and there's no such table in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I fixed this. Removing the metadata worked. But turns out I had updated to a more recent version of EntityFramework accidentally while trying to fix my problem and this more recent version expected different naming conventions for the Database. In any case recreating the many-to-many group person table with a script from a DB created by Entity Framework and deleting the metadata fixed the problem.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. It was not a new version of entity framework at all (thank goodness) rather it was simply a piece of code that I had commented out that defined the many-to-many relationship and without that piece of code EF expected something different.